# Failed to gem install nokogiri in Fedora16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, fedora

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p194 & Rails 3.2.9 in Fedora 16.
When I `gem install nokogiri`, it fails with error message:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/chelseaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've googled around for quite a while but only found some solutions for MacOS. I've no idea what to do, please help.

**Edit 1**
The results of `yum search iconv`:

```
mingw32-iconv-debuginfo.noarch : Debug information for package mingw32-iconv
mingw32-iconv-static.noarch : Static version of the MinGW Windows Iconv library
mingw32-win-iconv.noarch : MinGW Windows Iconv library
mingw32-win-iconv-debuginfo.noarch : Debug information for package
                                   : mingw-win-iconv
mingw32-win-iconv-static.noarch : Static version of the MinGW Windows Iconv
                                : library
perl-Text-Iconv.i686 : Perl interface to iconv() codeset conversion function
perl-Text-Iconv-debuginfo.i686 : Debug information for package perl-Text-Iconv
psiconv-debuginfo.i686 : Debug information for package psiconv
psiconv-devel.i686 : Development files for psiconv
uniconvertor-debuginfo.i686 : Debug information for package uniconvertor
mingw32-iconv.noarch : GNU libraries and utilities for character set conversion
perl-HTML-WikiConverter.noarch : Perl module to convert HTML to wiki markup
perl-HTML-WikiConverter-Markdown.noarch : Convert HTML to Markdown markup
psiconv.i686 : A conversion utility for Psion files
uniconvertor.i686 : Universal vector graphics translator
```

Comment: You should install all dependencies including libiconv package. I'm not familiar with fedora but on ubuntu sudo apt-get install libiconv

Comment: It seems fedora does not have such a package.

Comment: I'm amazed that this isn't in a Fedora repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it work, here are the steps:

- Download libiconv

  `wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.11.tar.gz`
- Extract files `tar -xvzf libiconv-1.11.tar.gz`
- Enter the directory `cd libiconv-1.11`
- Configure libiconv Library `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libiconv`
- Compile libiconv `make CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-tree-dce -fno-optimize-sibling-calls"` (I have to add CFLAGS to make the compiling work.)
- Install libiconv `sudo make install`
- Install nokogiri 
  `CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-tree-dce -fno-optimize-sibling-calls" gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/libiconv --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/libiconv/lib --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/libiconv/include`

Voila, it shows the success message!

Answer (score 5):

No need to compile it yourself, try running this command:

`sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel`

Or:

`rvm get head && rvm requirements run force`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yum install -y iconv-devel
```

and then:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: Yes, but the results seem unrelated. I updated my question with this info.

Comment: How about sudo yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri

Comment: I've tried that, and it seems ok. But when I run `irb` and `require 'nokogiri'`, it says `LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri`.

Answer (score -1):

Error message indicates `libiconv is missing`. Did you install it? you may need to install `libiconv` and `libiconv-devel` packages.

Comment: I've tried to install libiconv, but there's no such packages. It shows `No package libiconv available. No package libiconv-devel available.`

Comment: `No package libiconv-ruby available. Error: Nothing to do`